# Is there a way to reference the last build label of a project in CruiseControl.NET?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Is there a way to reference the last build label of a particular project in CC.NET? I have a project set to execute a task that needs to run only when Force Build is clicked, but the path of the working directory changes based on the build number of our main trunk.

Currently I have a workaround where we set an environment variable to the value of %ccnetlabel%, but this seems like a dirty way to do it, and I am curious to know if there is a way to refernce the build label of a project directly.

We are running CC.NET 1.4.4.49.

Comment: by build label do you mean svn revision number?

Comment: Yes and no, our build label is basically the revision number with a prefix specified. But I figured out how to reference it last night, I will be posting my solution shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that with 1.4.4.49 there is not a way to reference another project's build label. I got around this by adding the following XML to the project configuration:

```
<labeller type="stateFileLabeller">
   <project>Other-Project-To-Take-Build-Number-From</project>
</labeller>
```

What had happened was that once I figured out that %ccNetLabel% was actually the correct way to go about this, I tried just using it in this new project (we use %ccNetLabel% elsewhere which works fine). However, without specifying the labeller tag, %ccNetLabel% causes CC.NET to throw an exception saying that '%' was not expected.